# After creating a mysql user with all privileges, the user cannot create databases in phpMyAdmin and only sees information_schema table

Tags: networking, mysql, mysql5.5

This is a recurring problem for some reason...

Using mysql 5.5, I am simply trying to create a user that can connect to the database remotely, have access to all databases, and create databases.

I have created a user using:

```
create user 'dev'@'%' identified by 'abcdefg';
```

then granted all permissions using:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to 'dev'@'192.168.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'abcdefg' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

and the result is that the user cannot create databases, and can only see information_schema database for some reason.

```
Databases

Create database: Documentation
No Privileges

Database Ascending
information_schema
Total: 1
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: can you create databases with the root user ?

Comment: and what's the content of the table mysql.db, column Create_priv for that user ?

Comment: already tried a flush privileges and restart ?

Comment: just noticed: why 'dev'@'%' ? shouldn't that be 'dev@%' or just without quotes ?

Comment: @Elvis Hi, root can create DBs. Dev has everything set to 'N' in the users table - thought grant all would have amended that? Have flushed and restarted service. Used 'dev'@'%' as saw it in an article and on mysql website - will use yours if you belive that to be better. very confused... cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might be that you're using phpmyadmin from an address that doesn't match 192.168.% ? Maybe you're connecting locally and using localhost to connect.

You can verify this by setting different passwords for 'dev'@'%' and 'dev'@'192.168.%' and see which one works through phpmyadmin.

Make sure that the user you're connecting with *Combined with the correct host* has the needed privileges.